# How to append a vector layer using QGIS and Python?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, vector

I am working on scripting some data processing using QGIS and Python, but I'm running across issues that I need to debug.  Since my data is really large, and run-times can be lengthy, I would like to be able to write out results periodically and then append to those results so I don't have to re-run my scripts.

I'm outputting a polygon shapefile, and I am using the following Python code currently to work with the shp file:

```
poly_provider = poly_layer.dataProvider()    
fields = { 0 : QgsField("STAT_NO", QVariant.String) }

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("/localstore/data/shps/contrib_area.shp", "CP1250", fields, poly_provider.geometryType(), poly_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
  print "Error when creating shapefile: ", writer.hasError()

#processing...

def collect_geoms(geometries):
  if len(geometries) > 0:
    union_geoms = geometries[0]
    for geometry in geometries:
      union_geoms = union_geoms.combine(geometry)

    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry(union_geoms)
    fet.addAttribute(0, QVariant( point_feat_dict[point] ))
    writer.addFeature(fet)
```

The `collect_geoms()` function is then called in a loop, and when I'm done, I use `del writer` and I get the shapefile written to the disk.

Is there a way that I can write the shapefile out incrementally and append new polygons to it?  So for instance I can run 10 iterations of the loop, write the shapefile, and then run the next ten without overwriting the first set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
shp = "/localstore/data/shps/contrib_area.shp"
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(shp, "CP1250", fields, poly_provider.geometryType(), poly_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
# Just nuke the writer because we have already made our empty shapefile on disk.
del writer

# Open a reference to the new layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer(shp, "contrib_area","ogr")
dp = layer.dataProvider()

# in your process block
features = get10Features()
dp.addFeatures(features)
```

`QgsVectorDataProvider::addFeatures()` will write directly to the disk/datasource so that is the only method you should need to call.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  I spent a lot of time digging through the writer documentation trying to find a good solution.  I'll try this out and see if it works, might even reduce my memory footprint if `addFeatures()` writes to disk.

Comment: QgsVectorFileWriter is a bit ugly IMO.  There really should just be a `save()` method on the QgsVectorLayer class.

Comment: I agree.  On a similar note, @Nathan, do you know how efficient combining geometries is with Qgis?  Seems like when I get a large number of geometries it tries to hang (or it just takes a long time--several days!)  This is what is leading me to try to only do parts of my loop at a time to figure out where and why it is taking so long...